# Java Applet works in Browser but appletviewer shows wrong panel

Tags: java, browser, applet, panel, appletviewer

I have a Java Applet which works perfekt in the browser! Now i want to start it with the appletviewer but this starts an other panel than in the browser!?

I start it like this (the link is the same in the browser):

```
c:\appletviewer http://1.1.1.1/javaui?&panel=para/basePanel.pnl&lang=de_AT?panel=basePanel_StartJava/pnl
```

This is the html of the website:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>JavaUI</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <APPLET CODE="at.etm.javaui.JavaUi.class" ARCHIVE="javaui-1.0.jar"
   <PARAM NAME="type" VALUE="x-java-applet;version=1.5">
   <PARAM NAME="lang" VALUE="de_AT?panel=basePanel_StartJava.pnl">
   <PARAM NAME="panel" VALUE="para/basePanel_2.1.pnl">
   <PARAM NAME="debug" VALUE="0">
  </APPLET>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now my problem is that the appletviewer shows a Panel (Dialog) which is part of the Programm but not the Start Panel. It seems to me that the appletviewer doenst loads the parameters right? 
Does anyone have a tip for this?

Comment: Correct, [AppletViewer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97338_01/doc/forms.6i/a83591/appc.htm) does not run in a browser.

Comment: That's not what i asked ...

Comment: *Now i want to start it with the appletviewer but this starts an other panel than in the browser!?* I linked to the AppletViewer docs if you want to pass parameters that tells you how.

Comment: My problem is when i open the URL with:
Browser: It shows the correct View(Window/Frame/Panel or whatever you want to call it)
AppletViewer: It shows a different View (not the one it should)